# Eclipse Perforce Plugin and Defaulting the File Type Modifier so Version is Updated

Tags: eclipse-plugin, perforce, file-type

We migrated our version control system from CVS to Perforce and our Java dev team is using the Perforce plug-in in Eclipse (Mac). The version is no longer updating on adds/edits. We are using the $Revision keyword in our javadoc. According to the Perforce site, you have to use the +k modifier, effectively changing the file type from text to ktext. Two questions:

- Is there a way to default the file type to ktext (or set the modifier) in Eclipse, rather than having to do it each time before a submit (commit) to Perforce? (E.g., right-mouse clicking on the file and selecting Team > Change Attributes ...)
- Is there a way to configure Perforce to continue the versioning where CVS left off? Example: Before the migration, a file was set with 1.34. On the next Peforce submit, we want the file to be set with 1.35, rather than #1.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received a helpful response from Perforce's support team in case anyone else is having these issues:

Regarding defaulting the file type:

*You can provide this on the server-side with the "p4 typemap" command.  For example:*

*+k //depot/proj1/....java*

*will add the +k modifier to all files under //depot/proj1 with the ".java" extension.*

Regarding versioning:

*If you migrate your CVS repository to Perforce using one of the full 
conversion tools (e.g. cvs2p4, which can be found in our Public Depot at public.perforce.com), it will bring over all of the revisions from CVS, so that a file at revision 1.34 in CVS will be a Perforce file at revision #34 (making the next submit #35).*